# How can I make sure Firebase project members with only a viewer or editor role cant access stored user & email data

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project with accompanying webapp (website).
I am looking to create a commmunity on the site, with user accounts, logins and ability to post comments on the site.

I am the Firebase project owner and have some developers (viewer & editor roles) who maintain the site for me.

My concern is that if I create user accounts, my developers may get access to these user emails which compromises GDPR.

Is there a way in the Firebase database of a project, to hide user emails & password data from said developers or even myself?

Appreciate your advice

Comment: You can set detailed access controls for each user in the Google Cloud IAM panel.

Comment: Thanks Frank, so I went into IAM and saw a list of roles with number of permissions. I am assuming these permissions are equivalent to access controls?

When I clicked to view the excess permissions it gave me a list. The developers with viewer role can see firebaseauth.configs.get and firebaseauth.users.get.

However the list is uneditable as I cant delete actions in this list to restrict access controls.

Is there another way of restricting access control? maybe I am misunderstanding how to do this on IAM.

Comment: You can't change the permissions for a system defined role, but you can create a new role with just the permissions you want those collaborators to have.

Comment: Thanks. So are firebaseauth.configs.get and firebaseauth.users.get the only permissions that enable google project members to see user data?

Comment: O'm actually not sure what specific permissions exists for that, but I expect all of them to be under `firebaseauth`. Of the two you mention, `firebaseauth.gets.get` sounds like the one that allows getting the actual users, the other sounds like it's related to loading configuration data.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a play around and speak with firebase community to see how to actually set a new role with these permissions. I have no clue unfortunately!!  cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research and even hiring someone on fiverr to walk me through this I finally figured out what do do.

First as mentioned by Frank above I need to create a custom IAM role on Google cloud platform. The youtube tutorial below walks through how to do this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GTGSMW_-XQ

Second make sure that the permissions that you assign for them do NOT include any of the below.

Firebase Authentication permissions:
(firebaseauth.configs.create, firebaseauth.configs.get, firebaseauth.configs.getHashConfig, firebaseauth.configs.getSecret
firebaseauth.users.delete, firebaseauth.users.get, Firebaseauth.users.sendEmail, firebaseauth.users.update)

That's it pretty much

EDIT Aug 7th 2023: After some more experience I found an even simpler way to mitigate against this and is what I am doing now. First create a test project on fiverr and add your developers to this project. Ask the developers to pass on the html/css/java code that is used to deploy to this web app/website. Create a new project on firebase that only you can access and change the API key in the html/css/java code your developers passed onto you. Then you'll be able to deploy the website without them acessing the backend containing user data (as long you have proper authentication rules in place for Real time database).